# ListView with text and image - can I change the XML (or parameters) if no image exists?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a list of articles in a listView with text on the left, and an image on the right.  If the article doesn't have an image, I'd like the text to go full-width (as opposed to having a marginRight of 60dp).

My noob-java thought process is:  I'm already looping through and checking if there's an image... (if there is one, I change which image shows up) within that loop, can I somehow use java to alter the XML of my view to add or remove the imageView and add or remove the margin?

The code I'm using to repeat through and alter the image:

```
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.displayImage("", viewHolder.thumbView); //clears previous one
    if(article.filepath != null && article.filepath.length() != 0) {
        imageLoader.displayImage(
            "http://img.mysite.com/processes/resize.php?image=" + article.filepath + "&size=100&quality=70",
            viewHolder.thumbView
            );
    }
```

My "article_entry_list_adapter.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Layout for individual news entries in a list -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >

<!-- Title of the news entry -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/article_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@drawable/list_title_selector" android:typeface="serif"/>

<!-- Subtitle contains author and date -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/article_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/article_title"
    android:layout_below="@id/article_title" 
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/list_subtitle_selector" />

<com.sltrib.views.WebImageView
    android:id="@+id/article_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/super_light_gray"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:cropToPadding="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest changing your xml layout to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >

<!-- Title of the news entry -->

<com.sltrib.views.WebImageView
    android:id="@+id/article_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@color/super_light_gray"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/article_thumbnail"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Titol"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_title_selector"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtitol"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_subtitle_selector"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, when there is no image, just set the `WebImageView` visibility to `GONE` and the text will take the parent's width.

With your example:

```
viewHolder.thumbView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to show the image
viewHolder.thumbView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //to hide the image
```

Comment: This definitely seems more like what I'd want - cleaner / makes more sense. But it's not working.  The images are gone, but the text still doesn't expand to fit the width.  I'm on minSDK 8 - does that matter?

Comment: I removed the 60dp marginRight and it works!  Much more elegant than programmatically changing the margins imo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just while looping setVisiblity(VIEW.Gone) of article_thumbnail.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    textView.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

Comment: this doesn't take care of the text though - it still has a marginRight of 60dp

Comment: for that you can make one LayoutParams and use for that textviews

Comment: I add some example code how to change TextView's margin programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can either alter your viewGroup (setting visibility of your imageView to GONE and adding a margin programmatically) or choose to inflate another xml. As you want to do =)

Comment: I think I'd rather programatically hide/show the image and remove/add the margin...but how do I do that?

Comment: @Dave LayoutParams params = yourView.getLayoutParams(); params.setMargins(...); yourView.setLayoutParams(params); I think sthing like that should work